# How to make "select not in" clause using linq sql

Tags: c#, linq

I am making a sql query and I want to have the linq sql syntax.

Query SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM Customer
WHERE CustomerID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 3 CustomerID FROM Customer ORDER BY CustomerID)
```

Please suggest a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: explain more by add new and complete info, more people can help u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TOP` makes no sense without an `ORDER BY`.

Assuming you're paging the results sorted by the customer ID, try:

```
List<Customer> page = context.Customers
    .OrderBy(c => c.CustomerID)
    .Skip(3).Take(3)
    .ToList();
```